# the angle of a shifted cone and its equation

Tags: integration

How to get the angle of the cone if it is shifted ?? 
$$z= 1-\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}$$
$$\rho \cos(\phi)=1- \rho \sin(\phi)$$

then I can not get  the angle ! Do I have to get the angle when it is not shifted i.e. for the cone 
$$z=- r$$ and it is the same angle for the shifted one ?

Also How to get it is equation : $\rho$ as function of $\phi$? if I want to use spherical coordinates to get the volume of solid bounded by the cone and $xy$ plane ?

Comment: The equation $z=1-x^2-y^2$ does not describe a cone but an upside down paraboloid.

Comment: Sorry , I mean  $$z= 1-\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}$$ ...I wrote it wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking about is: given a right circular cone, find the angle $\alpha$ between the axis of symmetry and the direction from the cone's apex along its surface. If we could find a unit outward normal $\hat n$ to the surface of the cone and we knew a normal to the axis of symmetry pointing in the direction of the cone's vertex $\hat s$, we could find $\hat n\cdot\hat s=\sin\alpha$. In this case we know that $\hat s=\hat k$, the unit vector in the $z$-direction. The surface areal element method of finding the unit normal goes like this: parameterize the position vector along the surface
$$\vec r=\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,1-r\rangle$$
Then find the total differential along the surface
$$d\vec r=\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-1\rangle\,dr+\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta$$
Then we can get the vector areal element by taking the cross product
$$\begin{align}d^2\vec A&=\pm\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-1\rangle\,dr\times\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta\\
&=\pm\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r\rangle\,dr\,d\theta=\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r\rangle\,dr\,d\theta\end{align}$$
Because the outward normal points generally up for this cone. The the scalar areal element is
$$d^2A=\left|\left|d^2\vec A\right|\right|=\sqrt2r\,dr\,d\theta$$
So the outward unit normal vector is
$$\hat n=\frac{d^2\vec A}{d^2A}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,1\rangle$$
The other method is the gradient method. Find a function for which the surface of the cone is a level surface. One such is
$$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+z$$
For along the surface $f(x,y,z)=1$. Then
$$\vec\nabla f=\vec\nabla\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+z\right)=\langle\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},1\rangle$$
points normal to the surface and we see again by inspection that it is the outward normal. Its magnitude is
$$\left|\left|\vec\nabla f\right|\right|=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}+1}=\sqrt2$$
So the outward unit normal is
$$\hat n=\frac{\vec\nabla f}{\left|\left|\vec\nabla f\right|\right|}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\langle\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},1\rangle$$
Now, in either case we see that $$\sin\alpha=\hat n\cdot\hat s=\frac1{\sqrt2}=\sin\frac{\pi}4$$
So we have established that the apical half-angle $\alpha=\frac{\pi}4$.
Now, $\rho$ as a function of $\phi$ you pretty much have already because you have an equation that relates $\rho$ to $\phi$ and all you have to do is to solve it for $\rho$. In fact,
$$\rho=\frac1{\cos\phi+\sin\phi}$$
To get the volume, observe that $\phi$ goes from the north pole to the equator, so
$$\begin{align}V&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{\frac1{\cos\phi+\sin\phi}}\rho^2d\rho\sin\phi\,d\phi\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{2\pi}3\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\sin\phi}{(\cos\phi+\sin\phi)^3}d\phi\end{align}$$
To simplify the above denominator I would use employ a phase shift.
$$a\cos\phi+b\sin\phi=r\cos(\phi-\delta)$$
Where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt2$ and $\tan\delta=\frac ba=\frac11=\tan\frac{\pi}4$. So we let $\psi=\phi-\frac{\pi}4$ and we transform to
$$\begin{align}V&=\frac{2\pi}3\int_{-\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{\pi}4}\frac{\sin(\psi+\frac{\pi}4)}{\left(\sqrt2\cos\psi\right)^3}d\psi=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{\pi}4}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin\psi+\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos\psi}{\cos^3\psi}d\psi\\
&=\frac{\pi}6\int_{-\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{\pi}4}\left[\tan\psi\sec^2\psi+\sec^2\psi\right]d\psi=\frac{\pi}6\left[\frac12\tan^2\psi+\tan\psi\right]_{-\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{\pi}4}\\
&=\frac{\pi}6\left[\frac12+1-\frac12+1\right]=\frac{\pi}3\end{align}$$
This is in agreement with the mensuration formula for the volume of a cone
$$V=\frac13\pi r^2h=\frac13\pi(1)^2(1)=\frac{\pi}3$$